# Search through CSV, returning only exact fit value

Tags: php, csv

Again I'm working on a working CSV filter. It will search through about 500 lines of promotional code and return its amount to ajax receiver. The weird thing is, if I only enter 2 letters, instead of searching for exact fit, the php processor would return the result once it has found a value which contains my entered letters! I need it to look for only exact fit of 4-strings value.

Here's my code so far:

```
<?php
// if data are received via POST, with index of 'test'
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $promocodevalid = false;
    $file  = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
    $coupon = array($_POST['test']); 
    $coupondef = $_POST['test'];             // get data
    $coupon = array_map('preg_quote', $coupon);
    $regex = '/'.implode('|', $coupon).'/i';
    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
       list($promocode, $amount) = $line;

       if(preg_match($regex, $promocode)) {
           $validity = 1;
           echo $amount."[BRK]".$promocode."[BRK]".$validity;
           $promocodevalid = true;
           break;
       }
    }
   if(!$promocodevalid) {
       $validity = 0;
       echo $amount."[BRK]".$promocode."[BRK]".$validity;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: That seems like a lot of code to find an exact match in a csv file. I assume your post data contains a string that needs to be 4 chars long? and your csv has lines like `abcd,efgh,ijkl` ?

Comment: There's 500 rows in my csv while each contains 2 columns. First columns is the promotion code which is 4 chars long each ("kbhb","rwew","dsaw"... and so on). Second would be the value of the code.

Comment: change you regex to `$regex = '/^('.implode('|', $coupon).'),/i';`

Comment: @ArtemL it won't work. Even I enter the correct code it would return $validity as 0.

Comment: oh.. i see where error is.. why you are using regex? you can just put `if (strpos(strtolower($promocode), strtolower($coupondef)) === 0) {` instead of `if(preg_match($regex, $promocode)) {`. Also you can remove `strtolower` if your code are in lower and you are receiving `$_POST['test']` in lower too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid regexes where they are not needed. Search for `str*` function you need.
Above code should look like:

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $promocodevalid = false;
    $file  = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
    $coupondef = $_POST['test'];             // get data

    while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {  
       list($promocode, $amount) = $line;  

       // remove strtolower if you are have lowercase promocode, 
       // but probably leave a $coupondef lowered.
       if(strpos(strtolower($promocode), strtolower($coupondef)) === 0) {
           $validity = 1;
           echo $amount."[BRK]".$promocode."[BRK]".$validity;
           $promocodevalid = true;
           break;
       }
    }
   if(!$promocodevalid) {
       $validity = 0;
       echo $amount."[BRK]".$promocode."[BRK]".$validity;
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the answer you provided previously works perfectly : if (strtolower($promocode) == $coupondef) {

Comment: Yes, but here i removed CSV processing. And this is an answer while that was a comment, and it's not visible without checking what's in comments section.

Comment: I found that your current answer won't work. The previous one work perfectly fine with csv processing intact. Now even if I entered a correct code it would return $validity as 0.